# Why does my Powersell Console State "NotStarted" repeatedly after ive made file changes and created files. (using filesystemwatcher)

Tags: powershell

I am fairly new to writing scripts in ps1 files and I figured everything would go smoothly but now I am having issues. I am writing a script to watch a folder and the files in the folder (changed,updated,created). When a event is triggered the action should start the process of running a .exe. The script should loop continuously.
I am having an issue with the exe starting; its as if the filesystemwatcher does not recognize the files I change,update or create.
I will gladly appreciate you guys help,thanks!

```
while($true){
### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS 
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "C:\BigData\COLLECTION_A\L_READ"
$watcher.Filter = "*.xlsx*"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  
$watcher.NotifyFilter =  [IO.NotifyFilters]'LastAccess,LastWrite,FileName,DirectoryName'

### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED 
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $action
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Renamed" -Action $action

### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER AN EVENT IS DETECTED
$action = { Start-Process C:\Users\sammy\Documents\parsing Engine 1.0.exe}     
sleep 2}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing the output from Register-ObjectEvent. Since the PSEventJob was just created and hasn't been invoked yet (by an event) you see it as NotStarted.

```
PS> Get-Job 4

Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command                  
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------                  
4      e04ec31b-c2b...                 NotStarted    False                                ...
```

Once an event fires from your FileSystemWatcher you will see it shift to running.

```
PS> Get-Job 4

Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command                  
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------                  
4      e04ec31b-c2b...                 Running       True                                 ...
```

I typically swallow the output from Register-ObjectEvent by sending it to $null, since I don't care about them if they haven't fired.

```
### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED 
$null = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
$null = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $action
$null = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Renamed" -Action $action
```

Comment: Thank You Stephen. Thank you for clarifying